# Not able to select dynamic name pdf in cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

Getting the following error:

Error: A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:

> cypress\fixtures\cypress\fixtures*.pdf
> cypress\fixtures\cypress\fixtures*.pdf{{extension}}

Cypress looked for these file extensions at the provided path:

> .json, .js, .coffee, .html, .txt, .csv, .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tif, .tiff, .zip

Provide a path to an existing fixture file.

What is the correct way to give the path from fixture as the file names are dynamic.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried that gave you this error?

Comment: You can't. What are trying to do?